# Why insert_or_assign doesn't have iterator overload?

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++17

### Issue

In C++17, associative containers in standard library will have `insert_or_assign` member function, which will do what its name suggests. Unfortunately, it seems like it doesn't have iterator based interface for bulk insert/assign. I even [tried to compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8ZRd0QS7dEhggw2k) small example, and from the compiler error, compiler couldn't find suitable overload, and neither candidate was reasonably close to iterator based interface.

### Question

Why C++17 didn't include iterator based `insert_or_assign` for operations in bulk? Was there any technical reasons? Design issues?

### My assumptions and ideas

I don't see any technical reason to not add iterator based bulk insertion/addition. It seems quite doable. It needs to lookup the key anyway, so I don't see any violations of "Don't pay for what you don't use".

Actually not having the overload makes standard library less consistent, and kind of going against itself. Plain `insert` supports it, so I'd expect `insert_or_assign` to support that too. I don't think that not having the overload will make it "Easier to use correctly, and harder to use incorrectly".

The only clue left is this notice from cppreference:

> insert_or_assign returns more information than operator[] and does not require default-constructibility of the mapped type.

I'm not sure why this might be a limitation, as the associative container has access to all of the internals and doesn't need to deal with `operator[]` at all.

Binary compatibility is not applicable here, if I didn't forget anything. Modification will be in a header, and everything will need to recompile anyway.

I couldn't find any associated paper either. Splicing maps and sets doesn't seem to mention it. The feature looks like a phantom.

Standard could at least include `insert_assign_iterator`, so that one could write `std::copy(input_first, input_last, insert_assign_iterator{map});`, but standard includes neither.

Comment: Is there something with the question? Such low view count makes me a bit worried.

Comment: The standard library is woefully incomplete in other obvious points as well, like not providing hash functions for pairs. So, I guess they just made another addition and thought: "Well, that should cover all the cases *we* are are interested in, we'll see whether someone wants more of this." And this is not just the standard library, it's also visible in the language itself. Orthogonality does not seem to be a key consideration with C++ design.

Comment: @cmaster, solid point. I guess it is time for another proposal? Is there any place to get feedback on implementation and usages in general given that I'm just a student and not part of any big organization?

Comment: @cmaster: Pairs are a fundamental container? I don't think so. `std::tuple` makes `std::pair` quite obsolete.

Comment: @Incomputable: Are you looking for https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal?

Comment: @ChristianHackl And, is there a `std::hash()` overload for `std::tuple`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl, I feel kind of insecure due to my immaturity in these kind of things. How friendly is the community? I'm afraid they just won't have time for my proposal.

Comment: @cmaster: So? I was merely stating that pairs are no longer a fundamental container. If you want a `std::hash` overload, you could write a proposal to "them".

Comment: @Incomputable: Well, it might be a bit premature :) But then again, we are talking about an ISO standard here. It's expected to be quite serious "adult" business. I suggest you read everything at https://isocpp.org/std/.

Comment: @ChristianHackl And I was merely stating that the features of the standard C++ library are nowhere near complete in terms of orthogonality. The thing about `std::hash()` not being available for central, standard container types was just an example for that. I don't care the least what that standard container type is actually called, if the people defining the C++ standard library cared for orthogonality, there would either be no `std::hash()`, or there would be specializations for all container types the C++ standard library defines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`insert_or_emplace` is intended to be a better form of doing `some_map[key] = value;`. The latter requires that the `mapped_type` is default constructible, while `insert_or_emplace` does not.

What you're talking about is similar, but different. You have some range of key-value pairs, and you want to stick all of those values into the map, whether they have equivalent keys or not. This was not the problem that these functions were created to solve, [as evidenced by the original proposal for them](http://wg21.link/N3873).

It's not that they're necessarily a bad idea. It simply wasn't the problem the function was added to solve.

Comment: The link seems to be broken

Comment: @Incomputable: Fixed.

Comment: I'll wait for two more days to see if committe member shows up. I'll try to email original authors about it. I'll accept your answer if no better is added. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I emailed the author, he agreed with you